# Ajax doesn't update attribute in database

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Ajax does not update the viewed attribute after a lesson has been fully watched.

application.js:

```
$('#video').onended(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/courses/:id/lessons/:id/viewed',
    type: 'patch'
 });
});
```

lessons controller;

```
def viewed
  @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
  @lesson.update_attribute(:viewed, true)
end
```

lessons/show.html.erb:

```
<h2><%= @lesson.name %></h2>
<div id="video">
<video controls="true" width="auto" height="auto">
  <source src="<%= url_for(@lesson.file) %>" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
</div>
```

config/routes.rb:

```
patch 'courses/:id/lessons/:id/viewed' => 'lessons#viewed'
```

add_view_to_lessons migration:

```
def change
  add_column :lessons, :viewed, :boolean
end
```

Comment: Is this typo or real code `/courses/:id/lessons/:id/viewed` ?

Comment: @Зелёный the real code

Comment: so you're missing ids in the url 
`/courses/:id/lessons/:id/viewed` you should pass ids of actual records in database, for example `/courses/1/lessons/2/viewed`, also you can't have two same anchors in the url `/courses/:id/lessons/:id/viewed`. Read more https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: also this is wrong `courses/:id/lessons/:id/viewed`, 
two parameters can't have same name. 
you can change it to this: `courses/:course_id/lessons/:id/viewed`

Answer (score 0):

convert

```
patch 'courses/:id/lessons/:id/viewed' => 'lessons#viewed'
```

to

```
patch 'courses/:course_id/lessons/:id/viewed' => 'lessons#viewed'
```

and

```
$('#video').onended(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/courses/:id/lessons/:id/viewed',
    type: 'patch'
 });
});
```

to

```
const data = { course_id: "", lesson_id: "" }

$('#video').onended(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: '/courses/:course_id/lessons/:id/viewed',
    type: 'patch',
    data: data
 });
});
```

and

```
def viewed
  @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
  @lesson.update_attribute(:viewed, true)
end
```

to

```
def viewed
  @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:data][:lesson_id])
  @lesson.update_attribute(:viewed, true)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

routes.rb

```
resources :lessons do
  member do
    patch :viewed
  end
end
```

- use rails helpers, it will help you have consistency on the order of the segments, the variables, named_routes, etc

show.html

```
<h2><%= @lesson.name %></h2>
<div id="video" data-viewed-url="<%= viewed_lesson_path(@lesson) %>">
  <video controls="true" width="auto" height="auto">
    <source src="<%= url_for(@lesson.file) %>" type='video/mp4'>
  </video>
</div>
```

- I'm passing the URL as a data attribute of the `#video` element so I don't have to mess with URLs with javascript, let rails handle these things, it's really good at it

js

```
$('#video').onended(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: this.dataset.viewedUrl,
    type: 'patch'
 });
});
```

- get the URL from the element's data attribute

Answer (score 0):

First, let's fix the route:

```
path "/lessons/:id/viewed" => "lessons#viewed", as: :lesson_viewed
```

We don't need course's id if it is a named route unless we're actually doing something useful with that information.

I would recommend you to add a `data` attribute in your erb to specify the route to call

```
<h2><%= @lesson.name %></h2>

<div id="video" data-lesson-viewed-url="<%= lesson_viewed_url(@lesson.id) %>">

  <video controls="true" width="auto" height="auto">
    <source src="<%= url_for(@lesson.file) %>" type='video/mp4'>
  </video>
</div>
```

Notice the change in `<div id="video" data-lesson-viewed-url="<%= lesson_viewed_url(@lesson.id) %>">` line.

Now Ajax can simply call that route:

```
$('#video').onended(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: $('#video').data("lesson-viewed-url"),
    type: 'patch' // Can move the HTTP verb to data attribute as well, leaving this upto the implementor for now
 });
});
```